# Why training accuracy and validation accuracy are different for the same dataset with tensorflow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am training with tensorflow2.0 and tensorflow_datasets. But I am not understand: why does the training accuracy and loss and valdataion accuracy and loss are different?

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

data_name = 'uc_merced'
dataset = tfds.load(data_name)
# the train_data and the test_data are same dataset
train_data, test_data = dataset['train'], dataset['train'] 

def parse(img_dict):
    img = tf.image.resize_with_pad(img_dict['image'], 256, 256)
    #img = img / 255.
    label = img_dict['label']
    return img, label

train_data = train_data.map(parse)
train_data = train_data.batch(96)

test_data = test_data.map(parse)
test_data = test_data.batch(96)

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights=None, classes=21, 
            input_shape=(256, 256, 3))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, epochs=50, verbose=2, validation_data=test_data)
```

It is very simple and you can run it on your computer. you can see my train data and validation data are the same `train_data, test_data = dataset['train'], dataset['train']`.

But the train accuracy (loss) are not the same with validation accuracy (loss). Why is it happen? Is this the bug of tensorflow2.0?

```
Epoch 1/50
22/22 - 51s - loss: 3.3766 - accuracy: 0.2581 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/50
22/22 - 30s - loss: 1.8221 - accuracy: 0.4590 - val_loss: 123071.9851 - val_accuracy: 0.0476
Epoch 3/50
22/22 - 30s - loss: 1.4701 - accuracy: 0.5405 - val_loss: 12767.8928 - val_accuracy: 0.0519
Epoch 4/50
22/22 - 30s - loss: 1.2113 - accuracy: 0.6071 - val_loss: 3.9311 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
Epoch 5/50
22/22 - 31s - loss: 1.0846 - accuracy: 0.6567 - val_loss: 23.7775 - val_accuracy: 0.1386
Epoch 6/50
22/22 - 31s - loss: 0.9358 - accuracy: 0.7043 - val_loss: 15.3453 - val_accuracy: 0.1543
Epoch 7/50
22/22 - 32s - loss: 0.8566 - accuracy: 0.7243 - val_loss: 8.0415 - val_accuracy: 0.2548
```

Comment: What is the meaning of using the same data for the training and validation splits? The idea of having a validation split if to see how your trained model (using the training split) generalizes to unseen data (validation split) after each epoch. You could use this to prevent overfitting for example. Isn't it meaningless to use the same data for both training and validation split?

Comment: I know that. I use this for debug. At the very begging, I use different data for train and validation. But I found the validation is very high. I don't know are there same wrong with dataset or model? So use the same data for training and validation and found this issue.

Comment: @tidy:Do you use data augmentation on training and validation data?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you tried using different data for train and validation. By using that you found out that the validation accuracy is very high (during training). Then you thought it's a problem with your setup and wanted to to debug by using the same data for training and validation. And you expected to get the same training and validation accuracy at every epoch. If you'd get that, then you'd be concluding that there's no issue with your setup, correct? I'm not sure that's a meaningful way to debug this.

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski: No, I do not use data augmentation. The code on the question is all. Everyone can run it on installed tensorflow2.0 and tensorflow_datasets computer.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, you are right. Mybe that is not a meaningful way (One of the ways I tried). But the point is: should i got different accuray for the same dataset? Whether is a bug of tensorflow?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45277243/2616185 . According to that FAQ in the Keras docs, there are 2 modes for a Keras model: training and testing. The behavior is not the same in the 2 modes. If my assumption here holds that 'testing mode' can correspond to the validation part of your training, then you found your answer. If my assumption holds that is, I'm not 100% sure about that. Maybe some else can confirm that.

Comment: "Why isn't it same" is very easy to answer, unless your real question is "why is validation loss so high", which is more involved; is your question one or the other, or both?

Comment: @tidy I did a test on one of my toy models, setting the training split as both training and validation data. You can see the results for the first 5 epochs here https://imgur.com/a/3Etn5XG . I'm also not getting the same losses and accuracies for the training and validation data. I don't think it's supposed to work that way.

Comment: What if: 1 - You forget about the mirror strategy (I don't know what this is, but it's unnecessary, and maybe it has some weird effect - bug)  /// 2 - You load the dataset twice, so train and test are independent datasets? Maybe trying to iterate twice the same dataset for different functions can cause an issue? /// 3 - Check whether every `BatchNormalization` layer of your model has `training = True`.

Comment: It's true that you won't have the same metrics, but the difference is too huge and there is a problem indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the culprit here is BatchNorm.

Since you have a small dataset and large batch size, you only do 22 updates per epoch. The BatchNorm layer has a default momentum of 0.99, so it takes some time to move the BatchNorm running means/variances to values more appropriate for your dataset (which, given you do not normalise the pixel values away from the [0, 255] range, is pretty far from the typical `mean=0, variance=1` sort of range that neural networks are generally designed/initialised to expect).

The reason for the big discrepancy in train vs. validation loss/accuracy is because the training behaviour of batch norm versus the testing behaviour is very different, especially with so few batches. The mean of the data running through the network during training is very far from the running mean accumulated so far, which only updates slowly due to the default BatchNorm momentum/decay of 0.99.

If you reduce your batch size from 96 to, say, 4, you substantially increase the frequency of updates to the BatchNorm running means/variances. Doing this, plus uncommenting the `#img = img / 255.` line in your data parsing function, alleviates the train/validation discrepancy to a large extent. Doing so gives me this output for three epochs:

```
Epoch 1/7
525/525 - 51s - loss: 3.2650 - accuracy: 0.1633 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/7
525/525 - 38s - loss: 2.6455 - accuracy: 0.2152 - val_loss: 12.1067 - val_accuracy: 0.2114
Epoch 3/7
525/525 - 38s - loss: 2.5033 - accuracy: 0.2414 - val_loss: 16.9369 - val_accuracy: 0.2095
```

You can also keep your code the same, and instead modify the `keras_applications` implementation of Resnet50 to use `BatchNormalization(..., momentum=0.9)` everywhere. This gives me the following output after two epochs, which I think more or less shows that indeed this is the main cause of your issue:

```
Epoch 1/2
22/22 [==============================] - 33s 1s/step - loss: 3.1512 - accuracy: 0.2357 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
22/22 [==============================] - 16s 748ms/step - loss: 1.7975 - accuracy: 0.4505 - val_loss: 4.1324 - val_accuracy: 0.2810
```

Comment: Changing the moment is ok to prove a point, but isn't it bad for training with actual data? Maybe the mean and variance become too volatile and stop representing the whole data?

Comment: Yep it could definitely be too volatile in reality. This dataset with about 2k images is very small for training a resnet from scratch. In reality I would suggest finetuning a pretrained model for this task, or getting more data. Otherwise maybe using momentum=0.9 for the first few epochs and then increasing the decay would be a good idea. Plus normalising the inputs properly.